# Preventing horizontal scrolling in mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile

I have a very long line at the top:

```
#top-line {
  background: #00A1E0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

So I'm using `overflow-x: hidden` to prevent horizontal scrolling:

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #EDEDED;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It works OK, but in mobile phones I still can scroll indefinitely to the right.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: you should specify `width` or `max-width:100%` of html or body

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that long line, but I suspect there's a better way. What's the point of having such a long line if you don't want people to be able to scroll? Is that line image at the top of the page? Why does it need to be so wide? Have you considered using a background image on the body element instead?

Comment: What is the reason for width: 10000px; on #top-line?

Comment: @ralph.m There's already a background image, and its absolute positioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the width:100% or max-width:100% to prevent horizontal scrolling because you define the width of the area mobile device can occupy and by its nature it is occupying more than the width of the mobile width itself so define as 100% which will restrict it to mobile width.

Answer (score 2):

define body width

```
body{
 width:320px//or 100%;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might want to try if you've ended up here is to adjust this meta tag in the html head:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
html body(tag)
ontouchmove="blockMove()"

js(document)
function blockMove() {event.preventDefault() ;}
```

Comment: This will not only prevent horizontal scrolling, but it will prevent any scrolling including vertical scrolling too.