# Prevent scroll on smartphone

Tags: html, css, smartphone

I'm working on an application/website for smartphones.
The application is composed of 3 panels. The user has to slide his finger on the screen to make the hidden panels appear.

To achieve this, all my panels are in absolute position, one has left: -100% (the left panel) while the other one has a left: 100% (the right one)

The problem is that on smartphone, I can sroll horizontaly and see the right panel, even when I want it to be hidden

The html code

```
<body>
    <div id="right-panel">
    </div>        
</body>
```

the css :

```
 body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(200, 120, 120);
 }

#right-panel {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: ease left 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: hsl(2, 100%, 98%);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 14;
}
```

Do you know what I can do to prevent this problem (that doesn't happen on computer browsers)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663606/preventing-horizontal-scrolling-in-mobile-devices

I think this answers your question.

Comment: Not really :/
Both html and body have their width set to 100% in my css

Comment: I'm not seeing this happen in Chrome for Android. Is there a specific OS/browser combo that you're having trouble with?

Comment: http://infolimon.iutmontp.univ-montp2.fr/~philipb/ColorMyMood/test.html
Here is an example of my problem. If you scroll on the left, you will see the red rectangle, on Chrome / firefox / stock browser of android